# I am not getting actual response in angular while working with service file

Tags: angular

reponse in console:

```
    Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}
    closed: true
    destination: SafeSubscriber {closed: true, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}
    isStopped: true
    syncErrorThrowable: true
    syncErrorThrown: false
    syncErrorValue: null
    _parent: null
    _parentSubscription: null
    _parents: null
    _subscriptions: null
    __proto__: Subscription
```

register.components.ts

```
    CandidateRegisterRequest() {
        let username = this.registermodel.username;
        let email = this.registermodel.email;
        let phone_number = this.registermodel.phone_number;
        let password = this.registermodel.password;

        // let id = this.commonuserservice.getSession('employerLoginId');
        let body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, email: email, phone_number: phone_number, password: password });
        let service_response =  this.service.HandlePost(body);
        console.log(service_response)

    }
```

auth.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AuthService {
    private url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
    private response_code = null;
    private response_msg = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    HandlePost(post){
        return this.http.post(this.url, post)
        .subscribe(response => {
        this.response_code = response['code'];
        this.response_msg = response['msg'];
        return response;
        })
    }
    }
```

Here i am trying to send data in **POST** method from service file(angular)
But i am not getting actual response.

Instead of that i am getting above response.

Expecting response: **{"code":200,"msg":"success"}**

I am getting same response when i am doing api call in my component instead of doing it on service file.

Here i am just doing api call in service and sending exact response to components.

But getting some Unknown response as above.

Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `subscribe` to the `Observable` returned by `HandlePost(post)` method of your service.

```
CandidateRegisterRequest() {
        /****
           other stuff
         ****/

        this.service.HandlePost(body).subscribe((response) => {

        let response_code = response['code'];
        let response_msg = response['msg'];
           /***
              do some other stuff with service response
           ***/
        });


}
```

And in your service, you need to return the http request without subscribing to it:

```
HandlePost(post){
        return this.http.post(this.url, post);
}
```

You can check out the official `HttpClient` docs:

https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code for **register.components.ts** should be as following. Angular post method returns an Observable i.e. you need to subscribe in order to get the data,error...

```js
CandidateRegisterRequest() {
        let username = this.registermodel.username;
        let email = this.registermodel.email;
        let phone_number = this.registermodel.phone_number;
        let password = this.registermodel.password;

        // let id = this.commonuserservice.getSession('employerLoginId');
        let body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, email: email, phone_number: phone_number, password: password });
        let service_response;
        this.service.HandlePost(body).subscribe((res)=>{
         service_response = res;
        });
        console.log(service_response)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the Observable returned by HandlePost(post) method of your 
 service.

```
HandlePost(post): Observable<any>{
 return this.http.post(this.url, post);
}
```

Then subscribe to the observable

```
this.service.HandlePost(body).subscribe((res)=>{
 service_response = res;
});
```

If you want to put the httpoptions then include that also

```
HandlePost(post): Observable<any>{
 return this.http.post(this.url, post, httpOptions);
}
```